# Probability of a painted cube with at least one white face

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry

A large solid cube with edge length of $4$ cm. is made from white dice with edge length of $1$ cm., and and the whole surface of the cube is painted black. These smaller cubes are shuffled randomly.

A blind man (who also cannot feel the paint) reassembles the small cubes into a large one. What is the probability that there is a at least one white face outside this large cube?

I find it very difficult to solve but perhaps I am missing something. This is what I got to:

There are $24$ dice with 1 painted face, $24$ dice with 2 painted faces, $8$ dice with 3 painted faces, and $8$ dice with no painted faces. Calling them type 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively, the probabilities of choosing a dice of each type are: $P(T_1) = 3/8$, $P(T_2) = 3/8$, $P(T_3) = 1/8$, $P(T_4) = 1/8$. By Total probability theorem the probability of choosing a white face in a dice is:

$P(B_d)=P(B_d/T_1)P(T_1)+P(B_d/T_2)P(T_2)+P(B_d/T_3)P(T_3)+P(B_d/T_4)P(T_4)=(5/6)(3/8)+(4/6)(3/8)+(3/6)(1/8)+(6/6)(1/8)=3/4$

I think it is not easy to find the probability of having at least a white face in the cube from this. The probability of having a white face in a dice outside the cube is dependent on other faces. For instance, a dice with $3$ painted faces could make that upto $3$ faces on the cube are not white.

I tried an approach similar to Paul Sinclair's but I am not convinced it is a good one. The probability for a face to be white would be: $P(B)= (P(B_d))^{16}=(3/4)^{16}=(3^{16}/4^{16})$. Consequently, the probability that it is not completely white is $P(B^c)=1-P(B)=1-3^{16}/4^{16}=(4^{16}-3^{16})/4^{16}$.

If we consider for $i \in \{1, \ldots, 6 \}$ the events B_i = "the face i is white" and $B_i^c$ its complement, then: $P(B_i) = 3^{16}/4^{16}$ and  $P(B_i^c)=(4^{16}-3^{16})/4^{16}$. Thus:

$P(\text{At least 1 face is white})=1-P(\text{0 white faces})=1-P(B_1^c \cap B_2^c \cap B_3^c \cap B_4^c \cap B_5^c \cap B_6^c)=1-P(B_1^c)P(B_2^c | B_1^c)P(B_3^c | B_1^c \cap B_2^c) P(B_4^c | B_1^c \cap B_2^c \cap B_3^c) P(B_5^c | B_1^c \cap B_2^c \cap B_3^c \cap B_4^c) P(B_6^c | B_1^c \cap B_2^c \cap B_3^c \cap B_4^c \cap B_5^c) \approx 1-(99/100)^6$

Consequently:

$P(\text{At least 1 face is white})=1-P(\text{0 white faces}) \approx 1- (P(B_i))^6 = 1-((4^{16}-3^{16})/4^{16})^6 \approx 1-(99/100)^6 \approx (6/100)=0.06$

Comment: What have you tried? What stopped you from getting the answer? Showing your work in the question (you can edit it) can give people an idea of what kind of answer is appropriate.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Here, we expect users to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: Hint: he first needs to pick the correct type of cube for each position (how many random permutations achieve this?), and then for each position there's exactly one corner/edge/face (depending on the type) that he must place in the "outward" position.

Comment: Did you consider the complement rule? P(at least one white face) = 1-P(0 white faces)?

Comment: A comment on English: "dice" is a plural word. Traditionally, the singular form is "die". However, it is quite common for people to still use "dice" for just one, and this use is also officially recognized. But the plural is still "dice", never "dices".

Comment: Trying to figure the probability based on different orientations of different types of painted dice in different locations, while possible, would indeed be cumbersome to work through. But there is a simpler approach: Because of the symmetry of the situation, every face of all the cubes has an equal probability of being an outside face of the re-assembled large cube.

Comment: @DinkyDoe I did it. Please, tell me if you were thinking of the same approach as me.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for your feedback. I applied symmetry in my last approach, but I am not sure it is the right approach.